# Check whether all selects with name chosen[] is a value other than 0

Tags: jquery

How can I do so it checks all the selectors with name="chosen[]" does not have value 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/LWayp/16/

Comment: While I suppose a code sample could MAYBE have been more Stack Overflowish, I doubt it was needed... not sure why this question deserved close votes.

Answer (score 7):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LWayp/17/

```
var isAny = $('select[name="chosen_options[]"] option[value=0]:selected').length;
if (!isAny) {
    alert('No option values 0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of each select element via:

```
$('[name="chosen_options[]"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

If you only have three of them, you can setup an if condition to check them individually via `$('[name="chosen_options[]"]:eq(0)').val()` where eq equals 0, 1, and 2. For example

```
if($('[name="chosen_options[]"]:eq(0)').val()==0 || ($('[name="chosen_options[]"]:eq(1)').val()==0) || ($('[name="chosen_options[]"]:eq(2)').val()==0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
$('select[name="chosen_options[]"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
            alert('Choose one');
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LWayp/18/ try this!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="chosen_options[]"]:[value="0"]').length > 0
```